# Display data within XML tags in PHP

Tags: php, xml

The XML that's received is below. How can I get the values ('AI', '3', '20.78'...) and display them in PHP?
The values are always returned in that order but the length can vary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Item Type="AI" Chan="3" Value="20.78" Manual="OFF" Min="0.00" Max="100.00" Units="degC" Name="Workshop Temp" />
</Data>
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: This information you can find in google in less than 1 min time...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php  here is a full example , read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the documentation of [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) useful,

> SimpleXMLElement::attributes — Identifies an element's attributes

Return Values

> Returns a SimpleXMLElement object that can be iterated over to loop through the attributes on the tag.
>
> Returns NULL if called on a SimpleXMLElement object that already represents an attribute and not a tag.

here is how you should use it:

```
$str = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Item Type="AI" Chan="3" Value="20.78" Manual="OFF" Min="0.00" Max="100.00" Units="degC" Name="Workshop Temp" />
</Data>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach($xml->Item[0]->attributes() as $key => $att) {
    echo $att."\n";
}
```